# Java Swing : How to refresh JTable Model from another page button

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have 2 windows one window shown the `JTable` Model data, when double click the row will pop up a new window to edit the data, once submit how can I refresh the `JTable`?

Customer.java :

```
JPanel getJPanel() {
    if (jPanel == null) {

        jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(null);
        jPanel.setSize(new Dimension(792, 420));
        jPanel.add(getJScrollPane(), null);
        setUpTableData();
    }
   JScrollPane getJScrollPane() {
    if (jScrollPane == null) {
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(20, 166, 759, 241));
        jScrollPane.setViewportView(getJTable());
    }
    return jScrollPane;
}

   JTable getJTable() {
    if (jTable == null) {
        jTable = new JTable();
        jTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                new ContactEdit(name,email,phoneNo,phoneNo2,id).getJInternalFrame().setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
        String[] colName = {"No." ,"Name", "Email","Contact No. 1","Contact No. 2","ID"};
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(colName);
        jTable.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jTable.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        Font Tablefont = new Font("DialogInput",Font.BOLD,12); 
        jTable.getTableHeader().setFont(Tablefont);

    }
    return jTable;
}
   public void setUpTableData() {
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
    ArrayList<Address> list = sql.getContactLists();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String[] bill = new String[6];
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j += 6) {
            bill[j] = Integer.toString(i);
            bill[j + 1] = list.get(i).getName();
            bill[j + 2] = list.get(i).getEmail();
            bill[j + 3] = list.get(i).getPhoneNo();
            bill[j + 4] = list.get(i).getPhoneNo2();
            bill[j + 5] = list.get(i).getId();
        }
        tableModel.addRow(bill);
    }
    jTable.setModel(tableModel);
}
```

Edit.java

```
private JButton getJButton() {
    if (jButton == null) {
        jButton = new JButton();
        jButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(155, 138, 85, 25));
        jButton.setText("Update");
        jButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                Address a = new Address(jTextField1.getText(),jTextField.getText(),jTextField3.getText(),jTextField2.getText(),"");
                                    sql.updateContact(a, Integer.parseInt(getJTextField4().getText()));                 
                            Customer c = new Customer();
                            c.setUpTableData();
                getJInternalFrame().setVisible(false);
                getJInternalFrame().dispose();
            }
        });
    }
    return jButton;
}
```

On `JPanel` Load will call this `setUpTableData` to retrieve the data from database.
On the edit window, I have added an action listener on the update button to refresh the table, but I don't know how to make the jTable refresh the updated data? The setUpTableData on `ActionListener` give me Null Pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to give the edit window an instance of he other `JPanel`. (You can accomplish that by passing the panel in to the constructor of the edit window)  Then you can simply call the `setUpTableData()` method from inside the `ActionListener`.

The code to do this may look like the following:

**Edit frame constructor**

```
public EditFrame(CustomerListFrame cListFrame, ... other params) {
    this.cListFrame = cListFrame;
}
```

**Update ActionListener**

```
public void actionPerforment(ActionEvent e) {
    cListFrame.setUpTableData(the new data);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, sorry dont quite get what you mean by give an instance of e other JPanel? how to do that? Thank You

Comment: @newbie - my guess is that he means simply that when creating the other JPanel, this one should have a reference (given in parameter, for example) of the main panel, so that it would be able to call your method, from "there".

Comment: So inside the constructor do I need to specify anything?

Comment: When I call the setUptableData() method inside the actionlstener it prompt me error message said NullPointer

Comment: @newbie My guess is that you aren't properly passing an instance of the JPanel into the edit frame.  I am going to edit my answer to include more information

Comment: Hi, for ur example ur CustomerListFrame izzit the jtable window class name?

Comment: @newbie Yes.  THe CustomerListFrame is your class that contains the JTable.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried your method on Edit Frame i create a constructor
 private Customer c = null;
 public Edit (Customer c){ this.c = c; }
but on MainFrame jTable 
jTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
   public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
     //here i will visible the editFrame
     new Edit(  ).getJInternalFrame().setVisible(true);
     how do I pass in the class itself?

Comment: `new Edit(MainFrame.this).getJInternalFrame().setVisible(true)`  That will pass the current instance of `MainFrame` into the constructor for `Edit`.